# How to connect sensor to not damage raspberry

Tags: gpio, pi-3, sensor

Hi guys i have 2 questions:

I have got [this digital mercury tilt sensor](http://allegro.pl/modul-czujnika-przechylu-pochylu-rteciowy-i6403087996.html), which is taking on input 5V. The seller included this diagram on the module's listing:

[image: Mercury tilt switch module diagram]

It's really hard to find out what current raspberry can maximally get on GPIO pin. Thats why i dont know which resistors i should use to connect it safely. Sorry for the obvious question but I'm a beginner.

Secondly, is there any possibility to eliminate joint vibration in program, to make it less sensitive?

Comment: If you want a useful answer you will have edit your question to tell us what the sensor is and give a link to its datasheet.

Comment: Sorry
It is really cheap sensor, 
There is really no datasheet 
http://allegro.pl/modul-czujnika-przechylu-pochylu-rteciowy-i6403087996.html
Only the scheme how it works. 
If i can use the site to let you see

Comment: Guys Do you think that making something like that is going work? raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22841

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, if you are a beginner and you want to protect your pi, I would start with using an arduino as your power supply and as the interface between your sensor and pi.

I get Arduino Uno's and Nano's on ebay for less than five dollars each. I feel much better about burning out a $3 arduino than a $40 pi.

Connect the pi to the Arduino with a usb cable.  As you get more comfortable, then you can look into plugging directly into your pi.  But be aware pi and arduino operate on different voltages, so just because your resistor works on the arduino, it may not work on the pi.

Also, you can install the arduino IDE on the pi, and program the arduino directly, then you can use python to read and write to the arduino using serial commands.  It may take a bit of googling, but like I said before, I don't like burning out pi's.

Comment: Thanks for advice, unortunately I got no time to order arduino
Guys
Do you think that making something like that is going work?
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=22841

Comment: While this is kinda sorta interesting tangential information, it doesn't particularly answer the question.

Comment: @goobering I felt it answered the question before it was edited.  When this answer was written, the question was much more generic, hence the generic answer.